# How to write a session cookie in order to retain session when moving to another page

Tags: javascript, php, cookies, session-cookies

In my website, after users log in and moves to a different page, their session is lost and on going back to the previous page(where their session was created) the page is blank, obviously because session is lost

I have two pages

1. **Account.php** (where the session is created after loging in)

```
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="Options.php">Go to options</a>
      </li>

    <?php 
      //Start of session
      session_start();

      //Setting up databse connection
      require_once 'databaseconnection.php'; 
      $conn = mysqli_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password,$db_database);
      if($conn->connect_error){
         die("CONNECTION FAILED:".$conn->connect_error);
      }

      //Getting phone number and pasword provided by user in the login page (Not included in this)
      if (isset($_POST['lpho']) &&          
          isset($_POST['lpass'])){ 
          $lpho   = get_post('lpho');  
          $lpass= get_post('lpass'); 

      //Getting user information from database
       $q="SELECT * FROM members WHERE phone='$lpho'";

       if($q) {
       //If record exists 
       $querymember = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE phone='$lpho' "; 
       $memberidentity = mysqli_query($conn,$querymember);
       //To get number of rows
       $rowsno = $memberidentity->num_rows;
       //To fetch specific member column from database as an array
       $memberrecords = $memberidentity->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);

       $count=$rowsno;

       if($count>0){
       //$reqpass is user's password from the database which is specific to array no [7]
       $reqpass = $memberrecords[7];
       //If given password matches the required password...
       if($lpass==$reqpass){
         //Session details passed
         /*How do I put these in a cookie then load them on my next page */
         $_SESSION['lpho'] = $lpho;
         $_SESSION['lpass'] = $lpass;
       }
      } 
     }
    }
    ?>
```

2. **Options.php** (where the session dies when user navigates to it)

So my question in summary is how I can make a cookie in `Account.php` that saves `lpho`(phone) and `lpass`(password) then loads it to `Options.php` when user navigates to it.

```
<?php
    echo "This is the options page";
?>
```

Comment: save password in cookie is **really bad** idea. use other authentication method.

Comment: @appleapple only the session id is saved in a cookie. However the password would be saved in plain text in a session file on the server, which is still a bad thing. it would be best to hash it using `password_hash()` before saving it.

Comment: With the usual default settings, if a user is logged in to your page and then go to another page (without closing the browser) and comes back to your page before the session timeout, they should still be logged in.

Comment: @Nick thanks, I don't know it. I assume it would store all data in client side, it's not that bad, then. (but then, store a uid would sufficient)

Comment: @appleapple it's not as bad as sending it to the client, but the password would be stored in plain text on the server, and that is still a bad thing.

Comment: `if($q)` - This check will _always_ evaluate as true, since `$q` simply is a non empty string which you literally set in the line before.

Comment: You're also open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Comment: I would also recommend against using `->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM);`. Use `->fetch_assoc();` instead. Then you'll get an associative array with the column names as key. So you just need to do: `$memberrecords['password']` instead of having to know it's index no 7. Then the order of the columns won't matter at all.

Answer (score 0):

Using sessions in PHP with cookies relies on sending cookies in the headers of the page. This means that `session_start()` must occur **before any output from the page** (as any output causes headers to be sent, and they can only be sent once per page). In your `Account.php` file the first thing you do is output your `<li>` block, which will cause a `headers already sent` error when you try to set a cookie using `session_start()`. Move the `session_start()` to the beginning of each PHP file and that should resolve this problem. For example, in this file:

```
<?php 
  //Start of session
  session_start();
?>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link " href="Options.php">Go to options</a>
</li>

<?php 
  //Setting up databse connection
  require_once 'databaseconnection.php';
```

Note that storing passwords in plain text is a very bad idea (in your case, both in your database and the session file on the server). You should use PHPs [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) functions to store and check passwords.